# How can I force a specific value in the implementation of an interface method?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

This is something better explained with an example. Currently I have something like this:

```
public class Car {
    internal string SaleCode {get; set;} //Spring, Summer, ...
    public string Name {get; set; }  //Model name
}

public interface ICarFactory 
{
    Car GetSummerSaleCar();
    Car GetSpringSaleCar();
}

public class FordFactory : ICarFactory 
{
    public Car GetSummerSaleCar() {
        return new Car() {Name="Fiesta"};
    }
    public Car GetSpringSaleCar() {
        return new Car() {Name="Fusion"};
    }
}

public class CarProvider {
    public void ProduceCars(ICarFactory factory) {
        var inventory = new List<Car>();
        Car car = null;
        car = factory.GetSummerSaleCar();
        car.SaleCode = "SMR";
        inventory.Add(car);

        car = factory.GetSpringSaleCar();
        car.SaleCode = "SPG";
        inventory.Add(car);
    }
}
```

The SaleCode of the car should always be the same for each method, so the CarFactory implementation should not set this value. Right now I set this in the CarProvider class, but I'd like to know if there's a way to get this out of the interface. The only thing I can think of is to use an attribute applied to the method definition inside the interface where I can set the type, but I feel there must be another alternative.

Ideas?

## UPDATE

In case you're wondering, this is what I was talking about when I referred to adding an attribute to each method in the interface:

```
public class SaleAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
}


public interface ICarFactory
{
    [Sale(Code = "SMR")]
    Car GetSummerSaleCar();
    [Sale(Code = "SPG")]
    Car GetSpringSaleCar();
}

public void ProduceCars(ICarFactory factory)
{
    var inventory = new List<Car>();
    foreach (var method in typeof(ICarFactory).GetMethods())
    {
        String carType = null;
        var attributes = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SaleAttribute), false);
        if (attributes.Length == 1)
        {
            saleCode = ((SaleAttribute)attributes[0]).Name;
            Car car = (Car)method.Invoke(factory, null);
            car.SaleCode = saleCode;
            inventory.Add(car);
        }
    }
}
```

This has the added benefit that CarProvider doesn't need to be modified if a method is added in the interface. The disadvantage is obviously the overhead (performance and maintenance) associated with Reflection.

## UPDATE2

I changed the example from using Car Types to Sale Codes as this better reflects my situation.

Comment: How about an abstract base class which implements the interface and sets the type of the car?

Comment: Any particular reason why Type cannot be set during the creating of Car object?

Comment: You could auto-set the value in the Car class or use an abstract class instead of an interface. Also your FordFactory does not implement ICarFactory.

Comment: @TimMedora: The abstract class is a possibility, but just so I know, how would you implement it? I can only think of having an abstract method OnGetCompact that I can call from my GetCompact method. So, basically, having one pair of methods (one public and one abstract) for each car type. I'm not sure I like that.

Comment: See @Jaime Olivares solution. I was just about to post something similar (after thinking about it, I like it better than using an abstract base class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mike I think the best approach is to have an abstract type Car and two derived classes: CompactCar and MediumCar.

```
public abstract class Car { 
    internal string Type {get; protected set;} //Compact, Medium, Large, ... 
    public string Name {get; set; }  //Model name 
} 

public class CompactCar : Car
{
     public CompactCar() { this.Type = "Compact"; }
}

public class MediumCar : Car
{
     public MediumCar() { this.Type = "Compact"; }
}
```

So you can return the specific type like:

```
public interface ICarFactory      
{     
    CompactCar GetCompact();     
    MediumCar GetMedium();     
}  
public class FordFactory : ICarFactory    
{   
    public CompactCar GetCompact() {   
        return new CompactCar() {Name="Fiesta"};   
    }   
    public MediumCar GetMedium() {   
        return new MediumCar() {Name="Fusion"};   
    }   
}
```

This has minimum impact in the source code using it, since it can still reference the cars with the abstract type Car.

Comment: That's definitely a good option. Only thing is, in my actual implementation I actually have between 10 and 15 types, so that means creating 10 to 15 classes. I was looking for something that, when adding a new Type, would represent the minimum amount of changes in the code. But that's probably not feasible...

Comment: There is no way to add some logic in the interface. However, the different return types are in fact creating a rule in the interface. I don't see any other way to fulfill your requirement.

Comment: Well, there is one way I can think of, and that is using attributes. See the update in my question. But I'm not sure that's the best option.

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution, unless your unique goal is to space some hours of work. Your are delegating the responsability to the consumer of the classes. Even worst, potentially any of the methods can return the wrong model and you will enable it by setting the car type from the ourside. In that case, just set the type on each GetCompact and GetMedium method.

Comment: I don't think that this delegates the responsability to the consumers as they still need only to implement the factory. I agree with the second part of your comment when considering the example of the car types. I've updated the example to better reflect my situation, so you can see what I'm up to.

Comment: oh boy! switching from CarType to SalesCode changes everything! the problem with type is that it is inherently tied to the model and belongs to the Car's domain. SalesCode is a different story.

Answer (score 0):

how about `CarType.Create(Medium)` instead of `new Car`?

I am suggesting a factory called `CarType`

```
public class CarType{
   public class CarType(instName){
      this.instName = instName;
   }
   public Car Create(){
      return new Car(){Type=instName;}
      //or alternatively, if you have more implementations for the cars
      //return (Car)Activator.CreateInstance(this.instName);
   }
   public static CarType Compact = new CarType("Compact");
   public static CarType Medium = new CarType("Medium");
}
```

and the usage would be

```
Medium.Create(){Name="Fiesta";}
```

But that would still be within the CarFactorys method, so not much help for you...

Comment: The concrete car factory shouldn't be able to set the car type.

Comment: i ment CarType as a factory for Cars with set type... i was thinking of the "type-as-factory" pattern from this book: http://media.pragprog.com/titles/dhnako/toc.pdf

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I don't see much detail in the pdf that you linked to.